# How to decompse kinetic term operator in string compactification

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, supergravity

In general textbook, when we want to calculate the dimension of moduli space of string compactification, i.e. calculate the number of massless modes after dimension reduction, we use the following equation
$$\Delta_{10 d}=\left(d d^{\dagger}+d^{\dagger} d\right) \mathbf{X}_6+\Delta_{4 d}$$
This means that the kinetic term operator, or harmonic operator can be decomposed into the 4d part and the 6d compact space part. However, in general case, this is not true because $\Delta_{10 d}$ has mixed terms. So where does this formula come from? What kind of assumption does this formula use?